Bedeutungen von "ausrichten"
Ich wohne in Deutschland seit ein paar Jahren und erinnere mich nicht, das Verb "ausrichten" jemals im realen Leben gehört zu haben, aber die heutigen Hauptbedeutungen sind mir klar - entsprechend den englischen "align", "adjust"/"orient" und "host" (Punkte 3, 4 und 5 auf dem Duden-Artikel). Dass es häufig so verwendet wird, bestätigen zumindest die DWDS-Korpora und Reverso Context. Aber was die Bedeutungen "tell sb" (Punkt 1 auf dem Duden-Artikel: "im Auftrag eines anderen mitteilen, bestellen, übermitteln") und "accomplish" (Punkt 2 auf dem Duden-Artikel: "bei etwas Erfolg haben; erreichen, tun können, erwirken") angeht, bin ich mir gar nicht so sicher, da ich ihnen in den zwei oben genannten Ressourcen äußerst selten begegnet bin. Außerdem habe ich mir auch viel ältere Korpora angeschaut und herausgefunden, dass die beiden Bedeutungen vor 2-4 Jahrhunderten fast die einzigen waren, in denen das Wort verwendet wurde. Deswegen (wenn auch vielleicht nicht ganz begründet) nehme ich an, dass sie allmählich veralten und die Wörterbücher das noch nicht aufgenommen haben.
Ich möchte aber sicher sein und frage daher: Klingen Sätze wie "richte ihm Grüße von mir aus" und "du richtest damit nichts aus" euch als etwas, was ihr im heutigen Deutschen noch finden könntet?
P. S. Diese Frage und die Antworten darauf habe ich gesehen, aber konnte daraus leider nichts schließen.

"ausrichten" bedeutet daneben auch, etwas zu organisieren, zB könnte ein Sportverein einen Wettkampf ausrichten, Leute, die etwas zu feiern haben, ein Fest, etc..

@bakunin danke, ja, das ist die erwähnte Bedeutung aus Punkt 5 :)

Umgangssprachlich bedeutet "jemanden (Akkusativ!) ausrichten" auch noch "schlecht über jemanden reden". Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass das nur ein regional verwendeter Ausdruck ist. Ansonsten ist es heute hautpsächlich im Sinn von "mitteilen" verwendet. "bestellen" in diesem Sinn ist auch gut, aber das Wort 'bestellen', so verwendet, ist eher etwas, das ich als veraltert empfinde.

Das sind völlig gängige Bedeutungen des Verbs ausrichten. Wenn du sie in deiner Umgebung nicht hörst, liegt das vielleicht daran, dass der örtliche Dialekt ein anderes Verb benutzt.

Danke! Ich wohne in Hannover, falls du über seine Benutzung in der Region was sagen könntest. Dodezv meint auch, dass die Bedeutung "übermitteln" schon wesentlich formell ist, aber unter dem Post wurde angemerkt, dass er oder sie die zweite Bedeutung falsch angegeben hat, deshalb weiß ich nicht, inwiefern ich seinen/ihren Worten vertrauen kann.

Ich komm auch aus Ostfalen, und da sind diese beiden Bedeutungen eigentlich recht gebräuchlich. Also kann's daran nicht liegen, dass du es noch nie gehört hast.

Ich finde ausrichten für übermitteln gar nicht formell. Richt' ihm Grüße von mir aus!

Die Bedeutungen sind gängig, aber...
Bedeutung 1 ("Nachricht übertragen") wird aus zwei Gründen nicht so oft verwendet. Einerseits ist schon die Situation selten. In Zeiten des Internets kann man wichtige Sachen meist direkt mitteilen und braucht niemanden, der die Nachricht jemandem ausrichtet. Zudem klingt das Wort formell, für weniger formelle Anlässe kann man auch z.B. "Sag ihm für mich, dass..." oder "Grüß ihn von mir" verwenden.
In meinem Bekanntenkreis ist es z.B. denkbar, dass mir am Telefon zum Ende gesagt wird: "Grüß die Familie für mich." und ich dann der Familie mitteile: "Ich soll euch von ... Grüße ausrichten."
Bedeutung 2 ("erreichen") wird häufig in bestimmten Kombinationen genutzt, so wie "Schaden ausrichten" (vgl. Schaden anrichten) oder "nichts ausrichten können". Beide haben aber eine starke Verbindung zu Kämpfen und Konflikten. Ich sehe sie generell eher im Kontext von Videospielen.

Schaden wird angerichtet aber nicht ausgerichtet.
